# Angular2 : Need to create angular2 folder structure using latest angularCLI Webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, command-line-interface

> Angular2 : Need to create angular 2 folder structure using latest angularCLI Webpack
>   I have uninstalled old version of angular-cli and tried to install new
>   version of angular-cli@webpack but during installation itself I am
>   getting errors so ng new command also throwing some errors. Please
>   help me to resolve this problem.

### Uninstall , Cache Clean , Initiate installation

```
    D:\>npm uninstall -g angular-cli

    D:\>npm cache clean

    D:\>npm install --global angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2
```

### Errors during Installation

```
This is the error during installation of angularcli@webpack

"C:\Users\schinnathambi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_module
s\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node" exists.
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
C:\Users\schinnathambi\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\schinnathambi\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng
**npm ERR!** Windows_NT 6.1.7601
**npm ERR!** argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--global" "angular-cli@1.0.0-beta
.11-webpack.2"
**npm ERR!** node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package typescript@2.0.0 does not satisfy its siblings'
 peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.2.2 wants typescript@^1.9.0-dev

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ts-helpers@1.1.1 wants typescript@>=1.8.0 || >=1.9.0-d
ev
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer tslint@3.14.0 wants typescript@>=1.7.3

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\npm-debug.log
```

### Error while executing ng new command

This is the error while executing ng new command. I have reinstalled and installed again getting this same error always. This is the error while executing ng new command. I have reinstalled and installed again getting this same error always.

```
D:\>ng new sample
Error while running script "C:\Users\schinnathambi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\angular-cli\addon\ng2\commands\serve.ts":
Error: Cannot find module 'portfinder'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\schinnathambi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\angular-cli\addon\ng2\commands\serve.ts:6:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.require.extensions..ts (C:\Users\schinnathambi\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\cli\index.js:29:14)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Class.module.exports.includedCommands (
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the StackOverflow Help Center.

Comment: Explain clearly what you are doing, what the purpose is of what you're doing, don't post links to screenshots but copy and paste the actual error messages - the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page gives you a lot of tips.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will modify my question.

Comment: Done thanks , Will improve myself.

Comment: I am having the same problem...

Comment: Can you try after upgrading to npm3?  Here I am trying but unable to upgrade to npm3...

Comment: Please check my answer. Now its working for me

Answer (score 0):

> If you don't want to upgrade your existing npm  here is the way
>
> **Required : Node version above 4**
>
> Please execute following commands

### Install npm3 version >= 3

```
 npm install -g npm3
```

### Check npm3 version

```
 npm3 --version
```

> Close command prompt
>
> **Important: Open command prompt again with elevated priviliges**

### Uninstall old version of angular-cli and Install angular-cli@webpack

```
 npm uninstall -g angular-cli
 npm cache clean 
 npm3 install -g angular-cli@webpack
```

### Execute ng new SampleProject

```
 ng new SampleProject
```

> Your angular2 RC5 project folder is ready now with app module:)
>
> Above mentioned steps worked for me. Any queries please feel free to ask.